# TypeScript declaration generation including references

Tags: typescript

My team is currently upgrading to the new TypeScript 1.0 compiler and we have hit a stumbling block. In the old version of the compiler (0.8.3) when generating the declaration files the generated files did not include references to other needed files. As long as they were included in the compile everything was cool.

In the new version of the compiler, it is placing reference tags in the generated declaration files. It seems to be basing this off of the original source location so we are getting some real crazy references paths (shown below). Is there a way to disable this functionality (besides editing the compiler source)? Thanks!

```
/// <reference path="../../../../../../InternalApis/Controls/Diagnostics.d.ts" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Another Dev found that if you don't include the references in the code and just put all of them in the build it will not include the references in the generated files. Somewhat messy but we can still auto generate the declaration files.

Example:

```
// a.ts
export function main() 
{
    LogOut("Hello World");
}

// b.d.ts
declare function LogOut(text: string): void;

// Compile
tsc --declaration --module amd a.ts b.d.ts
```